# Attribute Error when creating Document Term Matrix

Tags: python, pandas, text, text-analysis

I am trying to create a Document Term Matrix expressed in the form of a Pandas dataframe. Here is my code so far:

```
df_profession['Athlete_Clean'] = df_profession['Athlete Biographies'].str.lower()
df_profession['Athlete_Clean'] = df_profession['Athlete_Clean'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([i for i in x if not i.isdigit()]))
df_profession['Athlete_Clean'] = df_profession['Athlete_Clean'].str.split()
df_profession['Athlete_Clean'] = [word for word in df_profession['Athlete_Clean'] if word not in punctuation]
df_profession['Athlete_Clean'] = [word for word in df_profession['Athlete_Clean'] if word not in stopwords.words('english')]

profession_dtm_athlete = pandas.DataFrame(countvec.fit_transform(df_profession['Athlete_Clean']).toarray(), columns=countvec.get_feature_names(), index = df.index)
profession_dtm_athlete
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the list objects in str() to convert them to strings:

```
df_profession['Athlete_Clean'] = str(df_profession['Athlete Biographies']).lower()
df_profession['Athlete_Clean'] = df_profession['Athlete_Clean'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([i for i in x if not i.isdigit()]))
df_profession['Athlete_Clean'] = str(df_profession['Athlete_Clean']).split()
df_profession['Athlete_Clean'] = [word for word in df_profession['Athlete_Clean'] if word not in punctuation]
df_profession['Athlete_Clean'] = [word for word in df_profession['Athlete_Clean'] if word not in stopwords.words('english')]

profession_dtm_athlete = pandas.DataFrame(countvec.fit_transform(df_profession['Athlete_Clean']).toarray(), columns=countvec.get_feature_names(), index = df.index)
profession_dtm_athlete
```

Comment: So that seems to have surpassed that problem, but now I'm getting "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index" Any suggestions on why this is appearing?

Comment: That error is internal to the pandas library, so I'm not sure. That may merit a fresh question. I'd recommend using the dataframe tag if you do make it a new question.

Comment: Okay, thank you JacobIRR. I will go ahead and create a new question regarding this new error.